# Django on Mac OS X requires install of MySQLdb

Tags: django, mysql-python

I tried setting up Django to use a MySQL database and it choked because the backend was not available. Reading around the net I see that MySQLdb needs to be installed, and perhaps _mysql needs to be installed as well. I have been surprised that so many different sets of instructions are available, which all seem to do different things in the install process. There are also a large number of posts about the problems with installing MySQLdb, and frequent comments about the install being a PIA.  This gives me pause, as I imagine that arbitrary choices which I may make may cause random and hard to track down bugs.

Is there a consensus on what the most reliable install method is?

I don't mind configuration issues. I'm just hoping not to create original problems. As a general rant, with MySQL being so common of a DBMS, why isn't the backend already installed in Django?

Comment: Django is a web framework. It would have absolutely no business including a database backend.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I suppose I was swayed by the siren call of Django having all tools included. SQLite's back end was already included, and changing the back end was just a line in the setting.py file, and with Django saying what to put in the settings file one would think it MySQLdb was there. Alas, not. Now, as a standard python library I understand why it is not included. As to best practices for the install, I'm wondering. Perhaps PEP 249 will help.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - It seems there is a bug in the Django documentation. In https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#engine it states that the built in backends include 'django.db.backends.mysql'. However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Any thoughts on who to mention this to? - Steve

Answer (score 0):

I use [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to install stuff like MySQL. It's pretty simple:

1. Install Homebrew:

   ```
    ruby -e "$(curl -fsSkL raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
   ```
2. Install MySQL using Homebrew:

   ```
    brew install mysql
   ```
3. Install the [MySQL Python module](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/1.2.4b1/) using your preferred Python installation mechanism (I prefer using Pip):

   ```
    pip install MySQL-python
   ```

> As a general rant, with MySQL being so common of a DBMS, why isn't the backend already installed in Django?

You can use other database backends with Django (SQLite or PostgreSQL, for example), and the MySQL connector itself is a module installed outside of Django (and potentially used by other software -- it many cases it might already be installed).

Comment: I have MySQL already installed. I am adding MySQLdb on top of a previous install of MySQL. pip as an install method for MySQL is yet another way I have seen for MySQLdb installation.

Comment: As @mipadi said, you need to ensure you have the python module that provides access to MySQL. Any reason you want to use MySQL instead of PostgreSQL? Most developers in the Django community seem to prefer the latter (including the core dev team for Django), and Django's ORM is advanced enough to where most use cases will be abstracted.

Comment: Yeah - My medical practice database runs MySQL. That the database isn't first order normalized is another issue -sigh- .  My, tough crowd here, got dinged for asking about the consensus view on installing MySQLdb, and no credit for my having researched enough to know that MySQLdb being missing was the problem. Maybe I shouldn't have disparaged MySQLdb being hard to install. Some touchy, developer, perhaps. Nonetheless, when I figure out how to install MySQLdb safely so that I can get my Django project interfacing with Macpractice I'll post back to stackoverflow. Folks here have been so kind.

Comment: Oh, by the way, the question was not how to install MySQL, but what is the consensus installing the Python package MySQLdb. @mipadi

Comment: @kd4ttc: There's no consensus, which is why there are a number of different methods. This is one common way.